# How to mark a check as warning or error if a check fails multiple times within a certain time range using Sensu?

Tags: sensu

A certain check works, but it should be checked multiple times within a certain range before a user gets notified.

There are [multiple Sensu attributes](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/checks.html#check-attributes) that could be configured. This list has been consulted, but no solution was found. Is it possible to mark a check as warning or error if a check fails multiple times in a certain time range?

Perhaps [aggregates](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/aggregates.html) would be an option, but should this not be used for multiple clients instead of using it for one check?

> ```
> {
>   "clients": 15,
>   "checks": 2,
>   "results": {
>     "ok": 18,
>     "warning": 0,
>     "critical": 1,
>     "unknown": 0,
>     "total": 19,
>     "stale": 0
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Take a look at Sensu filters and you will probably find out how to do it! Then write the answer here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [the `occurrences` filter](https://github.com/sensu-extensions/sensu-extensions-occurrences/), which is included [by default in Sensu](https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.28/reference/plugins.html#check-definition-attributes).

First, apply the filter to your handlers:

```
{
  "handlers": {
    "email": {
      "...": "...",
      "filters": ["occurrences"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your check, you can use the `occurrences` attribute to only trigger the handler once the check fails or warns a certain number of times in a row:

```
{
  "checks": {
    "check-http": {
      "...": "...",
      "occurrences": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.28/reference/plugins.html#check-definition-attributes

The `occurrences` as defined in the other answer was required (+1). The `refresh` and `interval` were needed as well.

Refresh and occurrences had to be assigned to a check. It was not needed to change the handlers.

```
"a-check": {
  "command": "echo hello"
  "occurrences": 6,
  "refresh": 60,
  "interval": 10
},
```

https://gist.github.com/calebhailey/8a30a00c6aadfebf7f767444f0a3df49

The `interval` means after how many seconds a check is executed. The refresh means that after `60 seconds` a notification is sent and the occurrences mean that if within 60 seconds the event was triggered 6 times that a notification will be sent.

It seems like the formula is as follows:

`occurrences` * `interval` = `refresh`

`10`          * `10`       = `100`